# Need to repeate data reading from multiple files using sas and run freqs on separate dataset created from separate files

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and facing few difficulties while creating following program.

My requirement is to pass the filename generated dynamically and read it so that don't have to write code five times to read data from 5 different files and then run freqs on the datasets.

I have provided the code below and have to write this code for more than 50 files:

**Code**

```
filename inp1 '/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1102_t1102_c10216_vEL5535.raw';
filename inp2 '/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1103_t1103_c10317_vEL8312.raw';
filename inp3 '/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1104_t1104_c10420_vEL11614.raw';
filename inp4 '/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1105_t1105_c10510_vEL13913.raw';
filename inp5 '/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1106_t1106_c10628_vEL17663.raw';

data test;

Do i = 1 to 5;

infile_name = 'inp' || i;

infile infile_name recfm = v lrecl=1800 end=eof truncover;

        INPUT 
                @1      E_CUSTDEF1_CLIENT_ID                          $CHAR5.
                @1235   E_MED_PLAN_CODE                               $CHAR20.
                @1090   MED_INS_ELIG_COVERAGE_IND                     $CHAR20.
                @1064   MED_COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE                       $CHAR8.
                @1072   MED_COVERAGE_TERM_DATE                        $CHAR8.
                ;

                if E_CUSTDEF1_CLIENT_ID ='00002' then 

                output test;
end;
run;

proc freq data = test;
tables E_CUSTDEF1_CLIENT_ID*E_MED_PLAN_CODE / list missing;

run;
```

Please help!!

Comment: Do you want the `PROC FREQ` to run against each file separately (as stated in your question title) or against the combination of all files (as in your example)?

Comment: Hi Bob,in my requirement, I need to run PROC FREQ against each file separately. I am not able to write down a logic through which I can pass the DATA SET name as a variable(generated through loop) as well as the Input file reference as a variable(generated through loop) and then run the PROC FREQ on each iteration on the dynamically named DATA SET.

Comment: Why do you need to have each file separately?  PROC FREQ with a BY statement will operate exactly as if each file were separate, without having to manage multiple datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example you can adapt.  There are different ways to do this, but this is one- depending no how you want the frequencies.

Step 1: Create a dataset, 'my_filenames', that stores the filename you want to read in, one per line, in a variable FILE_NAME.

Step 2: Read in the files.

```
data my_data;
set my_filenames;
infile a filevar=file_name <the rest of your options>;
<your input statement>;
run;

proc freq data=mydata;
by file_name;
<your table statements>;
run;
```

This is simple, data driven code that doesn't require macros or storing large amounts of data in things that shouldn't have data in them (macro variables, filenames, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, here is a SAS macro to read each file and run `PROC FREQ`:

```
%macro freqme(dsn);

data test;
   infile "&dsn" recfm = v lrecl=1800 end=eof truncover;

   INPUT  @1   E_CUSTDEF1_CLIENT_ID        $CHAR5.
         @1235   E_MED_PLAN_CODE             $CHAR20.
         @1090   MED_INS_ELIG_COVERAGE_IND   $CHAR20.
         @1064   MED_COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE     $CHAR8.
         @1072   MED_COVERAGE_TERM_DATE      $CHAR8.
         ;

   if E_CUSTDEF1_CLIENT_ID = '00002';
run;

proc freq data=test;
   tables E_CUSTDEF1_CLIENT_ID*E_MED_PLAN_CODE / list missing;
run;
proc delete data=test;
run;
%mend;

%freqme(/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1102_t1102_c10216_vEL5535.raw);
%freqme(/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1103_t1103_c10317_vEL8312.raw);
%freqme(/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1104_t1104_c10420_vEL11614.raw);
%freqme(/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1105_t1105_c10510_vEL13913.raw);
%freqme(/chshttp/prod/clients/coms/raw/coms_coms_relg_f1106_t1106_c10628_vEL17663.raw);
```

Note that I added a `PROC DELETE` step to delete the SAS data set after creating the report.  I did that more for illustration, since you don't say you need the file as a SAS data set for subsequent processing.

You can use this as a template for other macro programming.